# Docker configure physical location

Tags: docker

I have two disk machine and only one is SSD (exactly I am using Azure VM G-type)

Is there a simple way to configure docker to run images using SSD drive?

Answer (score 1):

See Docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/)

You need to specify the graph switch to the docker daemon. e.g.

`docker -d --graph="/var/lib/somewhere-else/docker"`